# How to ignore TargetNamespace in soap

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I have a Soap service generated by a wsdl file, that expects a certain TargetNamespace

`@WebResult(name = "getResponse", targetNamespace = "http://targetNameSpace1.com", partName = "result")`

but we have multiple clients calling this api and each one uses a diferente TargetNamespace:

Client one:

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:loc="http://targetNameSpace1.com">
    <soap:Header>
        <ns3:RequestSOAPHeader>
           ...
        </ns3:RequestSOAPHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <loc:getResponse>
            <loc:value>url/</loc:value>
        </loc:getResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Client two:

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:loc="http://targetNameSpace2.com">
    <soap:Header>
        <ns3:RequestSOAPHeader>
           ...
        </ns3:RequestSOAPHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <loc:getResponse>
            <loc:value>url/</loc:value>
        </loc:getResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the error i get:

```
<soap:Envelope>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Message part {http://targetNameSpace2.com}getResponse was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and i can only make it work with one at a time changing the targetNameSpace tag in the webResult, but my ultimate goal is to ignore this tag, because i dont know witch namespace will each client use.

At the moment i am trying to use an interceptor that extends this
`AbstractSoapInterceptor` and i get a SoapMessage object i can acess it before the request is made, but i can't seem to change the request, not sure if its the best aproach.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The wsdl and the (embedded) xsd are the contracts that you specify. Server and client need to follow that contract. Changing the contract single sided will result into invalid messages. Instead of looking for a solution to accept invalid messages you should update the clients so they obey the contracts.

Comment: You are correct, but the question implies that the clients are not under the asker’s control.

Comment: Yeah VGR is right, i do not have control in the clients request

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following this article https://www.javatips.net/blog/cxf-interceptor-example,

I intercept every request, and replace this:

`xmlns:loc="http://targetNameSpace2.com"`

with the url that i want, i used regex to replace whats inside the loc tag